# copy or move tool that will skip over error messages but will log them

Tags: file-management, file-synchronization

I'm looking for tool for moving/copying files/folder which will not hang on errors like directories cannot be deleted or created due to permissions, long file/folder names etc. but rather will continue to other files and will create some log file for later examination. Target OS: Windows 10/11 (but multi-platform is strongly welcomed)

Comment: `xcopy /C` or even `xcopy /C/Y` in a command window does much of what you want.

Comment: Not sure how easy it is to get that on Windows (though Cygwin might do the trick): on Linux I'd use `rsync` for that. Spits out errors if they occur, but continues nevertheless.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy), which comes pre-installed with Windows 7-10 and other versions (I believe that includes Windows 11). It is a command-line tool that you can include in a batch file if you need to repeat the same copying/moving operations at different times.

It has many options, including determining how many times to retry a failed copy or move attempt. The default is one million retries, which takes forever, so you should always override it with the `/r` option when used unattended.

Here’s an example of copying with one retry, and saving the log to a file:

`robocopy /r:1 /w:1 /np /s /log:LogFile.txt SourceFolder TargetFolder`

Here’s an example that moves **both** files and directories from the source to the target:

`robocopy /move /r:1 /w:1 /np /s /log:LogFile.txt SourceFolder TargetFolder`

Here’s a description of the options used above:

- `/r:1` Attempt only one retry on failed files
- `/w:1` Wait only one second between retires
- `/np` Don’t include progress in the log file
- `/log:LogFile.txt` Create a log file named LogFile.txt (or overwrite it) with names of successful and failed files
- `/move` Move files and folders instead of copying them

Answer (score 1):

[FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/) will solve this problem and it's written for Linux, Windows and macOS.

When configuring a job, ensure under sync settings - comparisons the `ignore errors` flag is set.